# i am creating a textarea,which allows user to input in hindi language. But when i am entering in textarea it is not showing text in hindi language

Tags: html, textarea, hindi

/* in this code i am trying to allow user to insert text in hindi language but when user insert text in textarea field it is showing in hindi*/

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="hi">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Hindi Text Input</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>हिंदी टेक्स्ट इनपुट (Hindi Text Input)</h1>
            <label for="hindi-textarea">टेक्स्ट इनपुट:</label><br>
            <textarea id="hindi-textarea" name="hindi-input" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        
            <div id="output"></div>
        
            <script>
               
                const hindiTextarea = document.getElementById("hindi-textarea");
                const outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
        
                hindiTextarea.addEventListener("input", function()
                {
                    const inputText = hindiTextarea.value;
                    outputDiv.textContent = "आपका इनपुट: " + inputText;
                });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: The `<textarea>` element should be language agnostic, you don't have to _enable_ non latin scripts. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish and how your code fails to meet your expectation, for the benefit of those of us who can't speak Hindi?